# MySQL UNION where clause condition from the first select

Tags: mysql, database

How can union two selections of the same tables but the second select condition depends on the first select attribute. Here is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_preference_header h
LEFT JOIN tbl_preference_detail d
OJ h.id = d.superid
WHERE h.type = 'CP' 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM tbl_preference_header h2
LEFT JOIN tbl_preference_detail d2
ON h2.id = d2.superid
WHERE h2.type = 'GP' AND d2.cat3code NOT IN (d.cat3code)
```

What I want is in the second select statement it will not contain all the cat3code from first select statement. There is error in my query d is not recognized in the second select statement.

How can I accomplish this ? What another method can I use other than union ?

Comment: You could use a subquery in your second select, what table is the `type` column on?

Comment: Sample data would help explain what you are trying to do .  Also, what table is `type` in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to reference the original query directly, but you could bring the original query into a subquery as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_preference_header h left join tbl_preference_detail d on h.id = d.superid where type = 'CP' 

union 

select * 
from 
    tbl_preference_header h2 
        left join tbl_preference_detail d2 on h2.id = d2.superid 
where type = 'GP' and d2.cat3code not in (
    select d.cat3code 
    from 
        tbl_preference_header h 
            left join tbl_preference_detail d on h.id = d.superid 
    where type = 'CP' 
)
```

Comment: Yess..you are right. why i didn't think of this one before. Thank you

Comment: Any idea how terrible this is for efficiency?  This is the only way I've been able to get a prioritized UNION without duplicates to work properly.  But having 2 of the same select queries in the same query seems like a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to figure out exactly what you want.  If I assume that `type` is part of `tbl_preference_detail`, then your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_preference_header h left join
     tbl_preference_detail d
     on h.id = d.superid
WHERE d.type = 'CP'  or
      (d.type = 'GP' and
       not exists (select 1
                   from tbl_preference_detail d2
                   where d2.cat3code = d.cat3code and
                         d2.type = 'CP'
                  )
      )
```

Comment: type is part of the header not detail